# Creación de archivos binarios en c#

Tags: c#

Como puedo hacer que mi código funcione, tengo uno que quisiera que me elimine un registro de una archivo binario, lo que quisiera es pedir el nombre u otra palabra de la linea del archivo para eliminarlo, hice esto pero no funciona que podría utilizar.

```
static void eliminar()

   {
        string estudiante;
        Console.Write("Ingrese nombre del estudiante a eliminar: ");
        estudiante = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        string ruta = @"C:\Users\Dell-PCTECHNOLOGY\Desktop\Programas\POO 2D D04 CARVAJAL DUVAL\Archivobin.txt";
        FileStream archivo = new FileStream(ruta, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
        int leer = 0;
        BinaryReader bescribe = new BinaryReader(archivo, Encoding.ASCII);

        string ruta2 = @"C:\Users\Dell-PCTECHNOLOGY\Desktop\Programas\POO 2D D04 CARVAJAL DUVAL\Auxiliar.txt";
        FileStream archivo2 = new FileStream(ruta2, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter bescribe2 = new StreamWriter(archivo2, Encoding.ASCII);

        while (leer != -1)
        {
            leer = bescribe.Read();
            estudiante = leer.ToString();
            string apel = leer.ToString();
            if (estudiante != leer.ToString())
            {
                bescribe2.WriteLine(estudiante);
                bescribe2.WriteLine(apel);
            }
            else if (apel != leer.ToString())
            {
                bescribe2.WriteLine(estudiante);
                bescribe2.WriteLine(apel);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("El estudiante " + estudiante + " fue eliminado con exito.");
            }
        }
        bescribe.Close();
        bescribe2.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Una recomendación seria que en archivos binarios tuvieras una longitud por registro. De esta forma tendrías delimitado el espacio que ocupan tus registros dentro del fichero, siempre tendrían que ocupar lo mismo y deberías extraer registro a registro para realizar la búsqueda.

Una vez encontrado el registro en cuestión, lo deberías sobreescribir con el registro siguiente machacando de atrás hacia adelante, o en el caso que fuera el último escribir '0' hasta el final (lo que vendría a ser desplazar el resto hacia arriba).

Espero ayudarte con la respuesta.